# Pagination breaks when I add a join and group statement to a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pagination, will-paginate

I have an index page with `Subscriptions`. A `Subscription` `has_many` `SubscriptionVersions` and I need to order them based on the latest `SubscriptionVersions`  `authorized_at` date.

This is my controller action

```
  def index
    @subscriptions = current_account.subscriptions
      .includes(:plan, :user)
      .joins("INNER JOIN subscription_versions
        ON subscription_versions.subscription_id = subscriptions.id")
      .group("plans.id, subscriptions.id, users.id")
      .order("MAX(subscription_versions.authorized_at) ASC")
      .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
  end
```

Removing the `join` and `order` statements, pagination works fine, but if I add them the results are not paginated.

What is going on and why?

Comment: It seems to be a limitation, as said in the wiki page of will-paginate : https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki#limitations

Comment: You can take a look at other gem, like Pagy : https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/migration-guide.html#gsc.tab=0